# Swift Array Map Skip Value

Tags: arrays, swift

Say I have the following code.

```
let myArray = [1,4,5,8,9,13,14,15]
let numbers = [4,8,13,15]
let finalArray = myArray.map({id in numbers.first(where: {$0 == id})!})
```

But I get an error because sometimes `numbers.first(where: {$0 == id})` returns `nil` sometimes and can't be unwrapped.

I know this isn't the best example but it's the simplest example to explain what I'm trying to do.

My goal in this example is to have `finalArray` be `[4,8,13,15]`. So IF `numbers.first(where: {$0 == id})` is `nil` just skip that value.

Is this possible with `map` in Swift? Or does the returned array length have to equal the array we are running `map` on?

Quick note. My example is very simple and in practice my problem is more complicated. I have my reasons for wanting to use `map` because it is an easy way to get a new array based on another array.

Comment: Just use flatMap instead of map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LeoDabus pointed out you should use `flatMap` instead of `map` in this situation. The reason is because `flatMap` can return `nil` since flatMap has the return type `U?` while `map` has the return type of `U` and can´t handle `nil`.

So this line, can handle `nil` with `flatMap`:

```
let finalArray = myArray.flatMap({ id in numbers.first(where: {$0 == id}) })
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Rashwan L's answer, I believe the Swift 4 version is as follows:

```
let finalArray = myArray.compactMap({ id in numbers.first(where: {$0 == id}) })
```